# Why is Leaflet issuing this warning in R/Shiny: Ignoring appended content; appendContent can't be used in a Shiny render call

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, gis

I am using tmap with leaflet in a Shiny app as I want to draw on a thematic map. However, creating the leaflet object using tmap_leaflet seems to generate a warning which I cannot find an answer for:

```
library(shiny)
library(tmap)
library(leaflet)

data(World)
world_vars <- setdiff(names(World), c("iso_a3", "name", "sovereignt", "geometry"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    t <- tm_shape(World) +
      tm_polygons(world_vars[1], zindex = 401)
    
    tmap_leaflet(t)
  })
  
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which results in:

```
Warning in renderWidget(instance) :
  Ignoring appended content; appendContent can't be used in a Shiny render call
```

The map is drawn, but I'm concerned I will encounter an error when deploying to Shinyapps as in this [previous posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847039/problem-publishing-shiny-app-warning-in-renderwidgetinstance-ignoring-appe) on SO.

Using tmap on its own is fine (but I can't draw circles) and Leaflet on its own is fine (but qtm is no match for thematic maps compared to tmap) and I don't want to hit a problem down the line.  I can suppress warnings but that's not getting to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`tmap_leaflet()` has an argument that you need to set if you're using it in shiny. Try using:

```
tmap_leaflet(t, in.shiny = TRUE)
```

instead. By default, it's set to `FALSE`.  Two features in `tmap_leaflet()` are not supported in {shiny}, and setting `in.shiny = TRUE` disables those features and stops the warning.